# WebDriverException() in Python2.7 using xvfb-run for chrome on Amazon Linux AMI Red-hat 7.2

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to run selenium for chrome through

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a -e /tmp/selenium.log -w 0 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

and getting error like

```
(<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException(), <traceback object at 0x7fc7cfc9c128>)
```

the strange thing is i am not even getting complete stack trace and the `-e` option for xvfb-run also is not returning any errors in file .

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
f = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
browser =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/local/chromedriver',chrome_options=f) 
browser.get(url)
browser.quit()
```

i also tried with 
`executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver'` and without executable_path

but getting the same error .

**it was initially working with python 2.6 with firefox** .

i checked maybe around 10-15 + similar questions even about how to enable more trace or debugging but none of the solutions seems to be doing the trick for me here.

selenium version 3.141.0

Edit : 
i updated some code to be able to get complete stack trace  and i got this error ,

> WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before
>   we could connect.

a bit more digging and saw its related to selenium/browser
 installed old selenium version 2.53

thus above error was gone but now i am getting connection reset by peer error for everything , below is stack

```
(<class 'socket.error'>, error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'), <traceback object at 0x1e1e320>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/Goose/src/goose/network.py", line 137, in get_html
    browser.get(url)
  File "/var/www/Goose/src/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/var/www/Goose/src/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/var/www/Goose/src/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/var/www/Goose/src/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 426, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1049, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 433, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 389, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 479, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

even `requests [security]` is installed as i had seen one cause to be that .

Comment: Update the question with error stack trace. We need to know from which line `(<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>, WebDriverException(), <traceback object at 0x7fc7cfc9c128>)` is coming.

Comment: @DebanjanB , edited to add more information ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it , 
the issue was the chrome browser and drivers were not properly installed , and their versions not compatible ,

installed latest chrome to run on the ami server using a script i got from 
https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/

installed perfectly , 
added few key arguments ,

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to driver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

and viola it started working ,